# SLL in c prints one extra random on the screen elements in list

Tags: c, linked-list

I run my code and it prints one extra random on the screen where we enter the element number, I wonder where did I make the mistake while creating the list?

```
struct emp {
    int x;
    struct emp* next;
};
typedef struct emp* node;

int main(){
    int elemanSayisi;
    struct emp *root,*iter;
    root=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct emp));
    iter=root;
    printf("enter number of elements: ");
    scanf("%d",&elemanSayisi);
    for(int i=0;i<elemanSayisi;i++){
        iter->next=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct emp));
        printf("\n%d. enter the element: ",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&iter->x);
        iter=iter->next;
        iter->next=NULL;
    }
    int b=1;
    iter=root;
    while(iter!=NULL){
        printf("\n%d. element: %d",b,iter->x);
        iter=iter->next;
        b++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your last element is created but never given a value. `iter->next=malloc(...)` then `scanf("%d",&iter->x);` then `iter=iter->next;`

Comment: how to fixed it? thank you :)

Comment: One way, start with `root = NULL` and build the linked list in reverse order.

Comment: That or handle the special case of the first item: `iter = malloc(sizeof(struct emp)); if (!root) root = iter;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handling the first node can be simplified using a pointer to pointer to emp. I also added code to free the list afterwards:

```
struct emp {
    int x;
    struct emp* next;
};

int main(){
    int elemanSayisi;
    struct emp *root = NULL;
    struct emp *iter;
    struct emp **ppemp = &root;
    printf("enter number of elements: ");
    scanf("%d",&elemanSayisi);
    for(int i=0;i<elemanSayisi;i++){
        iter = *ppemp = (struct emp *)malloc(sizeof(struct emp));
        iter->next=NULL;
        printf("\n%d. enter the element: ",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&iter->x);
        ppemp = &(iter->next);
    }
    int b=1;
    iter=root;
    while(iter != NULL){
        printf("\n%d. element: %d",b,iter->x);
        iter=iter->next;
        b++;
    }
    iter = root;                /* free nodes */
    while (iter != NULL) {
        root = iter->next;
        free(iter);
        iter = root;
    }
    return 0;
}
```